# Ear training software

Tags: ear, training

I recently discovered trainyourears.com, which is a website for ear training for audio engineers (EQ specifically).

The concept is easy; You listen to some modified audio, and you have to tell what modification has been done. The question I have is, how useful is this if you have no training in audio engineering?

Also, does anybody here know of other ear training software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coukd try with [golden ears](https://www.goldenears.philips.com/en/challenge.html#), is made by Philips for their sound engineers (they say)...

Comment: I used golden ears while at an audio engineering school.  I do think it can be _very_ useful.  It most certainly helped train me to be better at identifying frequencies.  +1

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout open-source online training Ear Gym https://eargym.gitlab.io/